# Start windows 10 in safe mode without logging in, and without recovery media

Tags: windows-10, safe-mode

I recently changed some display settings on my desktop pc, which resulted in the TV going black screen. 
The TV still works, I can enter BIOS, and the Acer logo also appears. But the screen goes black just before I reach the log on screen.

I do not have a recovery media. 
I have tried restarting several times to force it into safe mode, but it does not work. 
Pressing (and holding) F8 or shift during boot, does not work. 
I have also tried to turn it on and off by cutting of the power to force into safe mode, but no luck.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Win+R > msconfig.exe > Boot > Boot options > Safe boot > Select options. Or with command:: `bcdedit /set {default} safeboot minimal`. Restart required. See this [article](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-force-windows-to-restart-in-safe-mode-2625163).

Comment: @Biswa, those are certainly good suggestions, but the OP specifically emphasized that he wants to boot into Safe Mode *"without logging in."*

Comment: Does BIOS recognise the boot device (i.e.HDD or SSD)? Do you have any type of installation media of Windows or Linux? Can you open BIOS settings menu?

Comment: If you don't want to log into your Windows and use Advanced Startup, then your only choice, is to caused Windows to fail to load 3 times.  I encourage you to do it the correct way though if you care about your system integrity.  "I do not have a recovery media." - You should create one.  Download the current Windows 10 ISO.  It will come in handy to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Remote Desktop or something similar turned on, then try that first.

You may be able to Shift-Restart from the login screen.  I can't test it right now, but Windows is designed to have most commands usable just with keyboard entry.  You can do it blind : On another Windows 10 PC, restart and get to the login screen. 
 Figure out the keystrokes to highlight the Restart button, then hold Shift and hit Enter.  It's probably Tab, Tab to switch focus to the Power graphic, Enter to expand it, Down to choose Restart, and Shift-Enter to actually do the restart.  I don't know if Shift-Restart works from the login screen, please let us know.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. And thank you to everyone else for your  good suggestions :)